# What's the best way to structure a Multi-relational notes or updates table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, relational-database, structure

First off, I understand that this can sound like a question that is primarily opinion based. But I'm really not asking for anyone to supply different options, rather which of the following would be best.

> What I want to know is out of the below options, which is considered the closest to best practice, and which is considered a clean approach?

---

> **Please note:** I'm using php to handle information I/O so some options may require extra processing to complete a transaction.

## Issue

I work for a company that sells different kinds of products and has multiple pages for user interaction that we want to track.

## Solution

The solution I've come up with is to create a relational table to hold all of the updates that happen. I.e. when a new row is inserted into a table, another row is inserted into the `updates` table stating that the item was created on `2015-11-20 13:05:34` by `user_id` => `1`. When a row is changed, a new row is inserted into the `updates` table with a date and time and a note saying that it was Last Modified. To create this solution I've narrowed down the idea into a few options.

---

### ** Option 1

Create a table named `updates` with a column for every type of row with `_id` prefixed to it, a `user` column to state who performed the action, a date-time column, and a column to hold what the action was. The result would look similar to this:

```
+----+-------+-------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
| id | time  | user  |   action   | design_id | image_id | upload_id | ..._id |
+----+-------+-------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
|  1 | NOW() |     1 | "Deleted"  |           |       15 |           |        |
|  2 | NOW() | 10039 | "Created"  |           |          |     50678 |        |
|  3 | NOW() | 30845 | "Modified" |        11 |          |           |        |
+----+-------+-------+------------+-----------+----------+-----------+--------+
```

However there's something around 15-20 `*_id`s that would need to be created, and everytime we add a feature, we'll need to add another `*_id` column to this table.

---

### ** Option 2

Create a table named `updates` with a single `referring_id` column accompanied by a `type` column. basically, the `type` would correspond to the table that the action happened to and the `referring_id` would correspond to the specific row. The result would look similar to this:

```
+----+-------+-------+------------+----------+--------------+
| id | time  | user  |   action   |   type   | referring_id |
+----+-------+-------+------------+----------+--------------+
|  1 | NOW() |     1 | "Deleted"  | "image"  |           15 |
|  2 | NOW() | 10039 | "Created"  | "upload" |        50678 |
|  3 | NOW() | 30845 | "Modified" | "design" |           11 |
+----+-------+-------+------------+----------+--------------+
```

I'm thinking this is probably the best option because after it's in place, there's no need to add extra columns, and it seems easier to read.

---

### ** Option 3

Create a table named `updates` with nothing in terms of relational id, just that something was created/modified/deleted at a specific time by user `X`. Add a column named `update_ids` to every table that will hold a JSON or serializedArray string containing an array of ids corresponding to the `id` in the `updates` table. The result would be similar to this:

#### `Updates` table

```
+----+-------+-------+------------+
| id | time  | user  |   action   |
+----+-------+-------+------------+
|  1 | NOW() |     1 | "Deleted"  |
|  2 | NOW() | 10039 | "Created"  |
|  3 | NOW() | 30845 | "Modified" |
+----+-------+-------+------------+
```

#### `Images` table

```
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
| id | user  |                    filename                    |  updates  |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
|  1 |     1 | "085c30fce08b794130fe83f6967e03c3c7ecab8e.jpg" | "[1]"     |
|  2 | 10039 | "2387c0f43311c7bb2dc0c82c264d8ffaa09df570.png" | "[2]"     |
|  3 | 30845 | "699ee87816bc9b253a864a999ff92e3c6f0696c5.svg" | "[3]"     |
+----+-------+------------------------------------------------+-----------+
```

> **I sincerely appreciate any light you can shed on this subject.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1** is undesirable and is not in conformity with normal forms.

**Option 2** is the option I would instantly think about in such a case, since it is the exact relational description we are speaking about. However, if you need to frequently query the `updates` table, then the queries might get slow. If that will happen some time at the distant future, then you will need to create measures to work with the `updates` table, maybe caching, or helper tables. Do not prematurely optimize it, but you should know that the time might come sooner or later when you need to optimize it.

**Option 3** is difficult to be queried. Imagine when you want to query `updates` based on a small set of user ids. That is the definition of pain. But, if you can allow option 3, due to the fact that you will never need to do something like that, then this might be feasible as well.

Comment: Strange that you would use "relational" to describe option 2 when referring_id doesn't represent a single domain meaning the table doesn't actually represent a relation.

Comment: this table will only be queried when an admin needs to look into the history of an item or one of our web developers needs to overview the specific history of something. So I don't think it will ever be over-queried other than each database transaction will consist of at least 2 queries to be completed. Thank you!

Comment: @reaanb what other term would you use to describe such a pattern then? in terms of definition, a relational database is `a database structured to recognize relations among stored items of information.`. in this case, it would recognize the pattern by using the `type` and `referring_id`.

Comment: @iam-decoder For a more rigorous definition of relations in the context of databases see Codd or Date's writings.  Option 2 is reminiscent of the network model.  A relational version of it would be closer to option 3, except with an UpdatedImages table to relate images to updates rather than packing it into an array notation in a field in the Images table.  Normalizing option 1 would give the same result.

Comment: @reaanb Thanks for the reading material and explanation. I'll be adopting a network style table to handle this operation then! :)